# Tracing pyqt emit calls

Tags: python, events, pyqt

I'm in the process of profiling some PyQt code and cProfile returns a lot of calls like the following:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)

15/14    0.000    0.000    0.036    0.003 {method 'emit' of 'PyQt4.QtCore.pyqtBoundSignal' objects}
```

How can I trace which of these signals are being emitted? I'm assuming those calls to `emit()` are for several different signals.  However, it'd be useful to see which actual pyqtBoundSignal object is responsible for each call.

Also, what does `15/14` mean in the cProfile output for ncalls?